# How to delete a directory before exception is raised while opening an PIL Image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-imaging-library

How can I delete the `tmp` folder before raising an exception or before the end of the program?

```
flag1 = 0
flag2 = 0

with Image.open('tmp/image.jpg') as im:
    if flag1 == 0:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="HTTPException 1 Raised")
    if flag2 == 0
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="HTTPException 2 Raised")
```

Calling `shutil.rmtree('tmp')` before `raise` will cause `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process` error.

Comment: That problem seems like it should be wrapped inside of a `try except` block to catch the error and remove the file inside of the `except` block.

Comment: There is no error caused by the script, the exception is raised when a certain condition is not met ( for example: the image is not in 'jpg' format ), also calling ```shutil.rmtree('tmp')``` inside the ```except``` block will cause the same error.

Comment: Use a try except finally block. Put the `shutil.rmtree('tmp')` inside the finally block.

Comment: You could also consider to use the `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` library function, if this is at all applicable to the surrounding code in your situation.

Comment: Using ```finally``` block causes the same issue as well ```The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process```

Comment: ```tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()``` will not work in my situation, I need to create files in a specific path with specific file names.

Comment: You may be able to use [`Image.close()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.close) to relinquish access to the file so it can be deleted.